# Value assigned to struct member is incorrect

Tags: c, struct, enums, bit-fields

I am completely clueless as to what is going on here and would really like to know.

I have an enum:

```
typedef enum
{
    TAxCLK = 0,
    ACLK,
    SMCLK,
    INCLK

} TIMER_A_CLOCK_E;
```

and a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE byTimerSelection           :2;
    TIMER_A_CLOCK_E eClockSource    :2;
    INPUT_DIV_E eInputDivider       :2;
    TIMER_MODE_E eTimerMode         :2;

} TIMER_A_S;
```

where the other last two members are enums similar to the other and the first is simply an `unsigned char`. This `struct` is used to initialize a register on a microcontroller, so I limited each field to 2 bits.

I assign the members of the `struct` like so:

```
 TIMER_A_S stTimerInfo;

 // Setup Timer A
 stTimerInfo.byTimerSelection = 0;
 stTimerInfo.eClockSource = SMCLK;
 stTimerInfo.eInputDivider = INPUT_DIV_1;
 stTimerInfo.eTimerMode = UP;
```

The `eClockSource` member, however, is behaving strangely. The Code Composer debugger is showing the field as 32 bits instead of 2 and the value that is assigned to it in the end is -2 instead of 2. After some experimentation, I found that writing 0 results in it reading 0 and writing 5 to it results in it reading 2... What's going on? The other members behave just fine. It is a TI ARM compiler for a 32-bit controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's non-portable to have a bit-field of a type  other than `_Bool`, `signed int`, `int` or `unsigned int`.

A signed bitfield of size `:2` can hold values of `-2, -1, 0, 1`.  Since you seem to be getting those values, it means your implementation is making those bit-fields be signed.

It sounds like you wanted unsigned bitfields instead, so I would suggest using `unsigned int`.

NB. in a bit-field, it's implementation-defined whether `int` means `signed int` or `unsigned int`.  So if you use plain `int` it may still give different ranges depending on compiler or settings.

Comment: Re. the debugging issue, perhaps your debugger doesn't know about bitfields, or perhaps it promotes the result before displaying it

Comment: TIMER_A_CLOCK_E is an enum defined at the top of the question. And from what I've read / heard you can't force enums to be unsigned so that's a bummer haha. Guess I'll be redfining some things.

Comment: @SwarlesBarkely I'd just write `unsigned int eClockSource :2` etc. in your struct definition, there's no need to repeat the enum name in there.

Comment: "It's non-portable to have a bit-field of a type other than _Bool, signed int, int or unsigned int" -- enums would fall into this since they are treated as `signed int` right?

Comment: @SwarlesBarkely enums would fall into it because they are `enum` . The name `enum foo` is actually a type of its own, although in C the elements of the enum do not actually take on that type!

Comment: @ Matt McNabb Thank you for the clarification as well as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The standard allows the compiler to expand a bit field. Many do it for better performance. It is *VERY* common for compilers to implement

```
     unsigned somefield: 2 ;
```

as 32 bits. I discourage using bitfields entirely. They are not portable. If you need bitfields of a specific width, the best way is to insert and extract using bitwise operators.

Comment: The C standard requires that a bitfield of size `2` actually behave like a 2-bit integer (e.g. if it's unsigned and holds the value `3` and you increment it, it will result in `0`).  However there may be unused padding bits surrounding the field.